# Redshift COPY error what is the root problem of "error: Assert code: 1000 context: false - Invalid type:"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have tried to copy data from orc into redshift table and I receive the error:

```
ERROR: Assert Detail: 
----------------------------------------------- 
error: Assert code: 1000 context: false - Invalid type: 6551 query: 44660 
location: dory_util.cpp:361 process: padbmaster [pid=27395] 
----------------------------------------------- 
[ErrorId: 1-62340eaf-66cfc1cb4a51374b1ea75e4d]
```

I don't event know what the problem, I assume it is a datatype problem but no idea where. How to do get more info to be able to fix this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "schema"."table" (
    col1 varchar(256),
    col2 int,
    col3 varbyte,
    col4 timestamp,
    col5 timestamp,
    col6 int,
    "spid" int,
    col7 varchar(256),
    col8 varchar(256)
)
```

This is where the error occurs:

```
COPY "schema"."table"
FROM 's3://<bucket>/database/table/' IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/TestIAM'
FORMAT AS ORC
```

Comment: Wow, that's an internal Redshift error! I'd start by checking that all files in that S3 path are in valid ORC format. Make sure no other files have accidentally been included. You might want to remove all but one file in that location and progressively add the other files to find which one(s) are causing the problem. I wonder whether you could test the file format by using Amazon Athena?

Comment: internal Redshift error that is helpful. 

One I can confirm that it queryable in Athena I just ran a query against it, now it is a different schema such as varbyte vs binary and varchar vs string. Second can confirm there is one file in the location and it is ORC.